# R JRI java integration

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

I need help on this one: I installed JRI, everything is working. I can start the examples provided with rJava, but when I try my own code it's just a disaster. Here's the code:

```
re.eval(".libPaths('C:/Users/the_one/Documents/R/win-library/3.0');");
re.eval("library(forecast);");
re.eval("data<-scan('C:\\Users\\the_one\\Desktop\\RBRTEd1.csv');");
re.eval("plot(data, col=\"blue\", type=\'l\', main=\"Crude oil price 2009  until 2013\");");
re.eval("datats<-ts.(data,frequency=365;");
re.eval("arima<-auto.arima(datats,h5);");
re.eval("test1<-auto.arima(datats,trace=TRUE);");
REXP trace = re.eval("test1;");
System.out.println(trace);
re.eval("dataforcast<-forecast(arima);");
REXP fs = re.eval("summary(dataforecast);");


double[] forecast = fs.asDoubleArray();

for(int i=0; i<forecast.length; i++)
    System.out.println(forecast[i]);

re.end();
```

What I get is the following error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:143), pid=3956, tid=8456
 guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Users\the_one\Documents\R\win-library\3.0\hs_err_pid3956.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Answer (score 0):

Error solved, it was this part here:

`re.eval("data<-scan('C:\\Users\\the_one\\Desktop\\RBRTEd1.csv');");`